# python how to write list of lists to file

Tags: python, list, file-io

I am trying to write a list of lists of strings to a file. 
My big list is of the forme:

```
 1.0 '0:25.0' '1:50.0' '2:131.0' '3:202.0'
 1.0 '0:2.0'  '1:36.0' '2:131.0' '3:188.0'
-1.0 '0:56.0' '1:53.0' '2:55.0'  '3:58.0'
-1.0 '0:50.0' '1:51.0' '2:48.0'  '3:55.0'  
 and so on ...
```

the first column is of type int and the remaining are of type str.

I have tried the following code:

```
f = open('dataset', 'w')
for i in range(len(mylist[0]):
     f.write(str(item) for item in mylist[i])
f.close()
```

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

the error occured in line 3 of the above code (f.write(...))

EDIT:

I have tried:

```
 with open("train_data.csv", 'w') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f)
     writer.writerows(listdata)
```

But, surprisingly, for lines starting with -1.0 I only get the 1st 31 elements ( each line (list) contains 362 elements). I have no idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do like this.

```
from __future__ import with_statement

mylist = [[1.0,'0:25.0','1:50.0'],[-1.0,'0:56.0','1:53.0']] # as example

with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
    for _list in mylist:
        for _string in _list:
            #f.seek(0)
            f.write(str(_string) + '\n')
```

As a result, I get this in output.txt:

```
1.0
0:25.0
1:50.0
-1.0
0:56.0
1:53.0
```

Comment: I get the same error in the line :  f.write(_string + '\n')

Comment: Are you using python 2.7 or 3? I modified my answer to fit with python 2.7, in this case a f.seek(0) should solve your issue. Please try it out and let me know.

Comment: Thanks it works now after slightley modifying your code. I am using python 2.7. As you said no need for `f.seek(0)`, I moved the `f.write('\n')` out of the seconde loop and need to insert a space ' ' after writing each `_string`

Answer (score 19):

Use the csv library:

```
import csv

with open("out.csv", "w") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerows(list_of_lists)
```

`writerows` takes an iterable of iterables so the content of each sublist will be written to each row.

So for `list_of_lists = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` your out.csv would look like:

```
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

And as Scironic commented, you can pass whatever delimiter you want, i.e    `wr = csv.writer(f, delimiter=" ")` for a space etc..

Comment: Got there a bit before me. I'd point out that, if you don't want a comma delimited file, you can add in the `delimiter` argument to csv.writer and change the delimiter to anything you want(pipe, tilda, tab, space, nothing if you really want)

Comment: I have tried this code before, but surprisingly for lines starting with -1.0 I only get the 1st 31 elements (each line (list) contains 362 elements). I have no idea why this is happennig.

Comment: @GambaOsaca can you add that to your original question. Seems pretty important

Comment: @GambaOsaca, there is no logical reason that would happen, without seeing your actual input it is impossible to guess