# Python: how to write a list of list to a text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, arraylist

I have a list of lists as follows:

```
list_of_list = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]
```

I want to write down this to a `file.txt` in the following format.

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Note that the **commas** & **brackets** are not there in the `file.txt`.
I tried to flatten the `list_of_list` and wrote to `file.txt` but I got the following output:

```
1
2
3
etc.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python how to write list of lists to file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711899/python-how-to-write-list-of-lists-to-file)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
lst = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]]

text = '\n'.join([' '.join([str(j) for j in i]) for i in lst])

with open("file.txt", "w") as file:
    file.write(text)
```

`file.txt`:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
```

Comment: good answer, can be a bit more efficient with using a single loop and not creating 2 unnecessary lists in `join`: `with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
        for inner_list in list_of_list:
            f.write(' '.join(map(str, inner_list)) + '\n')`

Comment: @DeepSpace, you can consider posting that comment as an answer instead.

Answer (score 5):

```
with open('file.txt', 'w') as f:
    for lst in list_of_list:
        print(*lst, file=f)
```